# php: session value is not readable

Tags: php

my application having 5 files like index.html,login.php,logout.php,authenticate.php,home.ph

index.html simply directing login.php.

Login.php which reads the username and password from user using html form and posting using post method.

Authentiacte.php authenticates username and password.if authenticated then updating database as user logged in,starting the session for user_id and opening a home page home.php

from home.php i will redirect by using button named logout to logout.php

in logout.php i will update the database as user logout and redirected to index.html.

Here in **logout.php** I am not able to take the session value.
where as in **authenticate.php** the value will be set and checked also.

ie within web page the session is working . outside webpage session is not working.
below is my **logout.php**

```
<HTML>
  <HEAD></head>
  <body>
   <?php
   session_start();
   if(isset($_SESSION['User_ID']))
     {
      echo('<p'.$_SESSION['User_ID'].'</p>');
     }
     session_destroy();
   ?>
   </body>
  </html>


   In authenticate.php iam setting the session.

 authenticate.php


        <?php
        session_start();
          $_SESSION['User_ID']='1001';
        ?>
```

Comment: Add `session_start();` on top

Answer (score 0):

Before use session in new script . you should use [session_start()](http://www.php.net/session_start). also close `<p>` tag properly

```
<?php
session_start();
 if(isset($_SESSION['User_ID']))
  {
    echo '<p>'.$_SESSION['User_ID'].'</p>';
  }
?>
```

Comment: i.e <?php
session_start();
 if(isset($_SESSION['User_ID']))
  {
    echo('<p'.$_SESSION['User_ID'].'</p>');
  }
?>

Comment: Where you are setting value for User_ID. please make sure your session value is set. Please post code where you set value for User_ID

Answer (score 0):

use session_start(); as first line at logout.php

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure all pages have session_start();

if you have multiple include pages, you can use @session_start(); //It suppresses error messages - see Error Control Operators in the PHP manual.

This function will helps to check session is started or not,

```
  function is_session_started()
  {
     if ( php_sapi_name() !== 'cli' ) 
     {
        if ( version_compare(phpversion(), '5.4.0', '>=') ) {
           return session_status() === PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE ? TRUE : FALSE;
        } else {
           return session_id() === '' ? FALSE : TRUE;
        }
     }
 return FALSE;
 }

   // Example
   if ( is_session_started() === FALSE ) session_start();

   echo is_session_started();
```

also make sure that sesseion path is configured,

You can modify session save path on shared hosting by making custom php.ini.

```
   sessions.save_path = "/path/to/your/folder"
```

Otherwise, you can use

```
  ini_set(session.save_path, '/path/to/your/folder')
```

Answer (score 0):

Before calling any session variable you need to start the session using session_start(). This will resumes the current session based on a session identifier.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to start a session `session_start();` and to log out u need to end the session by using `session_destroy();` whihich is perfect for log out function